# Remove white space between thumbnail img and entry content

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a problem trying to remove the white space between the post image and the post content on my frontpage.

I would like to do that to put a background color after the image behind the content to have something a little bit like this : http://themeforest.net/item/total-responsive-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/6339019 (in portfolio).

If I do that now by adding `.loop-entry-content { background-color: #F2F2F2; }` there is a space between my image and my post title.

I'm currently using the theme Twenties which you can see here: http://themeforest.net/item/twenties-clean-responsive-blog-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/7876029

Some help would be highly appreciated :) Thanks

Comment: create a demo with relevant code

Answer (score 0):

check following class

```
.loop-entry-media {
    margin-bottom:20
}
```

you need to change `margin-bottom : 0;` as follows

```
.loop-entry-media {
    margin-bottom:0
}
```

also find .loop-entry-content class and add following code tho it

```
.loop-entry-content {
    background: #f7f7f7 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 15px;
}
```